# Putting padding between string and border in TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

How would I put padding between a string and the border to said string in TCPDF. I'm not seeing any way to do that in the Text() method.

Do I have to use another method? Is there anyway to accomplish this?

This would be an example of code I'm using:

```
$pdf->Text(130, $margintop, $fieldkey, false, false, true, 'B', 0, '', false, '', 0, false, 'B', 'T', false);
```

Comment: Did you try setting the cell-padding? http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a374b24751bf76e4ca5ba7694f87ec2c1

Comment: That works. Feel free to post it and collect your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TCPDF assigned default-values to the cell-paddings, which can be overwritten:

```
$pdf->setCellPaddings( $left = '', $top = '', $right = '', $bottom = '');
```

Or, with using the same padding for all sides:

```
$pdf->setCellPadding( $padding );
```

See the documentation here: <strike>http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a374b24751bf76e4ca5ba7694f87ec2c1</strike>

<strike>**Update 22.04.2020:** https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_SetCellPadding</strike>

**Update 20.08.2020:**
https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc-copy/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_SetCellPadding

Comment: page not found.

Comment: latest found here: https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc-copy/TCPDF/class-TCPDF/#_SetCellPadding

Comment: Now found here: https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_setCellPadding